# Send email from specific user using gmail javascript api

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I'm looking to send out an email (specifically the values entered into a form) from a specific gmail account, and due to platform limitations I have to use client side (i.e. javascript) code to do so.  I'm testing the following code, but it seems to be using my *personal* gmail credentials, rather than the client id I'm trying to specify.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Base64/1.0.0/base64.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var CLIENT_ID = 'myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];
  var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send';
  function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }
  function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES
    });
  }

  // ucs-2 string to base64 encoded ascii
  function utoa(str) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
  }
  // base64 encoded ascii to ucs-2 string
  function atou(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(str)));
  }

  function submitForm(form) {
    var formid = form.id.length>0 ? '('+form.id+') ' : '';
    var bodyText='The form '+formid+'was filled out on '+window.location.href+'\r\n'+
                 'The following values were submitted:';
    for (var i=0;i<form.childElementCount;i++) {
        bodyText += '\r\n'+'\r\n'+form[i].name+'\r\n'+form[i].value;
    }
    var unencodedEmail = 'To: '+form.attributes.getNamedItem('data-submit-to').value+
                         '\r\nSubject: A form '+formid+'was filled out on '+window.location.href+
                         '\r\n'+bodyText;
    try {
        var authInstance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        authInstance.signIn({ client_id: CLIENT_ID });
        try {
            var base64EncodedEmail = utoa(unencodedEmail);
            var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
                'userId': 'me',
                'resource': {
                  'message': {
                    'raw': base64EncodedEmail
                  }
                }
              });
            request.execute(function() {/*do post email sending stuff*/});
        } finally {
            authInstance.signOut();
        }
    } finally { 
        return false;//prevent the form from redirecting
    }
  }
</script>

<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
  onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Josh, with [EmailJS.com](https://www.emailjs.com) you can connect your Gmail account and then use it to send pre-built email templates using a simple js library (disclosure: I'm one of creators). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use other people's credentials, you need to use your own. If you follow the [Javascript Quickstart for Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js), you'll find out that the credentials will be from your Google mail account. This is the reason we have a thing called [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). If Google allowed that, this would be open to exploitation and malign use.

Comment: To be clear, I want to use a single, specific account under my own control.  I am aware that in general account impersonation/delegation is a security nightmare, but I was wondering if there was a safe, controlled way to do this.  FWIW, it looks like what I am requesting is [theoretically possible with a Service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#formingclaimset), but even that feels, at best, fraught with pitfalls.

Comment: A further thought regarding the Service account idea: DON'T DO IT.  Service accounts are designed to be used with compiled or server-side applications, and should not be exposed to end users.  It would be very easy to hijack the service account and reuse it for other nefarious purposes.